How do i import win32ui on python?
I have a problem importing win32ui on vscode.
the error message I get is 'Import "win32ui" could not be resolved from source'
I have tried to uninstall and re install pywin32 with
pip install pywin32
and
pip install pywin32 --user
but only win32gui and win32con are correctly imported.
the version i am trying to install is pywin32-306
i have tried to run the 'testall.py' file from win32 witch outputed me
'FAILED (failures=1, errors=14)'

i really don't know what to do

What python and pywin32 version are you using? Please share a [mre] so that we can see exactly what you're doing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You might want to make sure that you're running the same Python in VSCode as you are in the console. In the meantime as a quick fix, you might want to consider pulling up Powershell with ctrl + ~, make sure your terminal is in your working directory for your python project, then use python yourfilename.py. If you don't know how to navigate to the working directory, you can go to your Python directory in your file explorer and shift + right click in blank space next to files and click "open with Code"
